# Alignment in cases

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cases

I have this text in LaTeX:

```
$$
sgn(x)=
\begin{cases}
   -1 & \mbox{za podmínky } x>0\\
    0 & \mbox{za podmínky } x=0\\
    1 & \mbox{za podmínky } x>0
\end{cases}
$$
```

[image: sgn]

But I would like to move the "0" and "1" more to the right. I need to move these numbers just below "1", not to have it below "-".

Comment: You could add `\phantom{-}` in front of the `0` and `1`

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should define a new command using `\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}` at the preamble such that you can use `\sgn(x)` instead of `sgn(x)`.

Comment: Also see [Why is `\[` …`\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simplest is probably to use  `\phantom{-}1`

Answer (score 25):

Referencing my [chat message from 2013-04-05](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=8837549#8837549), here is the definition of the  `cases` environment that accepts one optional argument, the column specification of the left column. Thus writing `\begin{cases}[r]` the left column is set right-aligned.

This way you actually could even use `siunitx`’ table typsetting with the `S` column.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{cases}[1][l]{\matrix@check\cases\env@cases{#1}}{\endarray\right.}
\def\env@cases#1{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}#1@{\quad}l@{}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\sgn(x)=
\begin{cases}[c]
   -1 & \text{za podmínky } x>0\\
    0 & \text{za podmínky } x=0\\
    1 & \text{za podmínky } x>0
\end{cases}
 \]

 \[
 \sgn(x)=
 \begin{cases}[r]
    -1 & \text{za podmínky } x>0\\
     0 & \text{za podmínky } x=0\\
     1 & \text{za podmínky } x>0
 \end{cases}
 \]

 \[
 \sgn(x)=
 \begin{cases}[{S[table-format=-1.0]}]
    -1 & \text{za podmínky } x>0\\
     0 & \text{za podmínky } x=0\\
     1 & \text{za podmínky } x>0
 \end{cases}
 \]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This definition of `cases` is absolutely great (I am just tired of doing `phantoms` ;)). Please consider adding/sending your improvement to the `amsmath` package.

Comment: I get Package amsmath Error: Old form `\matrix' should be \begin{matrix}.

Comment: @Nermin I don't using TeXLive 2022 and `amsmath 2022/04/08 v2.17n AMS math features`.

Answer (score 9):

The `cases` environment of the `amsmath` package uses `array` with the column specification `@{}l@{\quad}l@{}`. Thus `\multicolumn` will work, e.g.:

```
\multicolumn{1}{@{}r@{\quad}}{...}
```

The alignment can also be influenced by `\hfil` and `\hfill`, because `array` or `tabular` are using `\hfil` to align and justify their column types `l`, `c`, and `r`.

```
\hfill 0 % puts 0 to the right
```

The following example shows the different methods:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{cases}
    \mbox{left/default}   &       \mbox{left/default} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{\quad}}{\mbox{left}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}     {\mbox{left}} \\
    %
    \hfil  \mbox{center} & \hfil  \mbox{center} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{\quad}}{\mbox{center}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}     {\mbox{center}} \\
    %
    \hfill \mbox{right}  & \hfill \mbox{right} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}r@{\quad}}{\mbox{right}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}r@{}}     {\mbox{right}} \\
    %
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}p{10em}@{\quad}}{Column type p \dotfill\newline with two lines \hrulefill} &
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}p{10em}@{}}     {Column type p \dotfill\newline with two lines \hrulefill} \\
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Applied to the case of the OP:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}

\begin{document}
\[
  \sgn(x)=
  \begin{cases}
         -1 & \mbox{za podmínky } x>0\\
   \hfill 0 & \mbox{za podmínky } x=0\\
   \hfill 1 & \mbox{za podmínky } x>0
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your text to make its English a bit more idiomatic. I trust you're OK with that.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks, of course I am OK with the corrections. I have also updated the image.

Comment: Brilliant, just use \hfill for baby cases! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative solution, which uses `array` for better alignment control:

```
\begin{align*}
    \sgn(x)=\left\{
    \begin{array}{lll}
    -1& \mbox{za podmínky} & x>0\\
    0 & \mbox{za podmínky} & x=0\\
    1 & \mbox{za podmínky} & x>0
    \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \sgn(x)=\left\{
    \begin{array}{ccc}
    -1& \mbox{za podmínky} & x>0\\
    0 & \mbox{za podmínky} & x=0\\
    1 & \mbox{za podmínky} & x>0
    \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \sgn(x)=\left\{
    \begin{array}{rrr}
    -1& \mbox{za podmínky} & x>0\\
    0 & \mbox{za podmínky} & x=0\\
    1 & \mbox{za podmínky} & x>0
    \end{array}\right.
\end{align*}
```

**Result**:
[image]

Comment: @daleif: This old post got upvoted recently, which reminds me: why not make a centered `dcases` into `mathtools`? Something like `\newcases{cdcases}{\quad}{%
  $\m@th\hfil\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\lbrace}{.}` That said, I think the package document should mention `\newcases` command.

Answer (score 3):

For a more global take on this, you can adjust the alignment of `cases` to be `r`ight-`l`eft rather than the default (`l`eft-`l`eft). Here's how:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\makeatletter
\def\env@cases{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}r@{\quad}l@{}}% Changed from \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}
}
\makeatother
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sign}{sgn}

\begin{document}

\[
  \Sign(x) = \begin{cases}
   -1 & \text{za podmínky } x > 0 \\
    0 & \text{za podmínky } x = 0 \\
    1 & \text{za podmínky } x > 0
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

You'll note that the alignment comes from the `array` column specification `@{}l@{\quad}l@{}`, which can be adjusted to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Just another simple approach.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\[
    \sgn(x)=
    \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
     -1 & \text{ za podm\'inky } x>0\\
      0 & \text{ za podm\'inky } x=0\\
      1 & \text{ za podm\'inky } x<0
    \end{aligned}
    \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a typo, `<` should be changed to `>`!

Answer (score -1):

Before considering the positions of `$0$` and `$-1$`, one should use `\cases` typographically right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$
sgn(x)=
\begin{cases}
   -1 & \mbox{za podmínky } x>0\\
    0 & \mbox{za podmínky } x=0\\
    1 & \mbox{za podmínky } x>0
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\mathrm{sgn}(x)=
\begin{cases}
   -1\text{,} & \text{za podmínky  $x>0$;}\\
    0\text{,} & \text{za podmínky  $x=0$;}\\
    1\text{,} & \text{za podmínky $ x>0$.}
\end{cases}
$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: But this doesn't really answer the question. Also see [Why is `\[` …`\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)